# charset issue with accents retrieving DB2 values with php over odbc

Tags: php, db2, odbc

I'm trying to do a select from a DB2 through PHP and odbc and then save those values on a file. The OS where the code is being executed is Debian. What I do is the following:

```
$query = "SELECT NAME FROM DATABASE_EXAMPLE.TABLE_EXAMPLE";
$result = odbc_prepare($server, $query);
$success = odbc_execute($result);
$linias = "";

if ($success) {
    while ($myRow = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
        $linias .=format_word($myRow['NAME'], 30) . "\r\n";  
}

generate_file($linias);


function format_word($paraula, $longitut) {
    return str_pad(utf8_encode($paraula), $longitut, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

function generate_file($linias) {

    $nom_fitxer = date('YmdGis');
    file_put_contents($nom_fitxer . ".tmp", $linias);
    rename($nom_fitxer . '.tmp', $nom_fitxer . '.itf');

}
```

The problem is that some of the retrieved values contains spanish letters and accents. To make and example, one of the values is "ÁNGULO". If I var_dump the code on my browser I get the word fine, but when it's write into the file it apends weird characters on it (that's why I think there is a problem with the charset). I have tried different workarounds but it just make it worst. The file opened with Notepad++ (with UTF8 encoding enabled) looks like:

[image: Notepad++ capture]

Is there a function in PHP that translate between charsets?

**Edit**

Following erg instructions I do further research:

The DB2 database use IBM284 charset, as I found executing the next command:

```
select table_schema, table_name, column_name, character_set_name from SYSIBM.COLUMNS
```

Firefox says the page is encoded as Unicode.
If i do:

```
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($paraula));
```

I get bool(false) as a result.

I have changed my function for formating the word hoping that iconv resolve the conflict:

```
function format_word($paraula, $longitut) {
    $paraula : mb_convert_encoding($paraula, 'UTF-8');
    $paraula= iconv("IBM284", "UTF-8", $paraula);
    return $paraula;
}
```

But it doesn't. Seems like the ODBC it's doing some codification bad and that is what mess the data. How can I modify the odbc to codificate to the right charset? I have seen some on Linux changing the locale, but if I execute the command locale on the PC I get:

```
LC_NAME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_ES.UTF-8"
...
```

Comment: What type is the corresponding field in the database? What is the encoding of the data stored in that field? If you var_dump in the browser, what encoding is used by the browser to display the data correctly?

Comment: The type of the field it's an alphanumeric type. The encoding used for the database is EBCDIC. I didn't put any <meta> tag on the code when I print it on the browser.

Comment: And what does the browser say if you press F10 to show the menu, and then choose 'View' -> 'Encoding' (Firefox)?

Comment: Also check what php thinks `$paraula` is encoded in, check `mb_detect_encoding($paraula)`.

Comment: It says that it's being encoded by Unicode (doing the Firefox 'View' -> 'Encoding' you mentioned)

Comment: If php thinks the raw data is already utf-8 encoded, what happens if you simply omit the call to `utf8_encode()`?

Comment: Excuse me, it returns false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to summarize from the comments into an answer:

First note that PHPs `utf8_encode` will convert from `ISO-8859-1` to `utf-8`. If your database / ODBC-Driver does not return `ISO-8859-1` encoded strings, PHPs `utf8_encode` will fail or return garbage.

The easiest solution should be to let the database / driver convert the values to correct encoding, using its `CAST` function: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_castspecification.html

Try to alter your query to let DB2 convert everything to UTF-8 directly and omit the `utf8_encode` call. This can be done by altering you query to something like:

```
SELECT CAST(NAME AS VARCHAR(255) CCSID 1208) FROM DATABASE_EXAMPLE.TABLE_EXAMPLE
```

Thanks to Sergei for the note about `CCSID 1208` on IBM PUA. I changed `CCSID UNICODE` to `CCSID 1208`.

I do not have DB2 at hand here, so the above query is untested. I'm not sure if this will return utf-8 or utf-16..

Comment: Throws me an obdc_prepare() error saying that symbol UNICODE is not valid. The error it's throw in spanish and there are missing letters on the error (as the system wasn't even capable of get the correct charset)

Comment: how can i assign to the driver the correct encoding?

Comment: any other way to solve it please? I'm still stuck on this.

Comment: Your approach works changing a little bit the query: SELECT CAST(NAME AS VARCHAR(255) CCSID 1208) ... 1208 is the equivalent of UTF-8 with IBM PUA. It doesn't work with the UNICODE statment.